# Is there any way to interact with the text selection menu in nativescript angular?

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to add an option to the text selection menu, in a TextView, and pass the selected text to an Angular component. Is this possible in NativeScript? I'm looking for a solution for both platforms.

Comment: It's possible, but you will have to write native code. Use [OnCreateContextMenuListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnCreateContextMenuListener) on Android native view instance & [UIMenuController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimenucontroller?language=objc) on iOS.